# Wagtail: Dynamic image generation and caching

Tags: python, caching, wagtail

I'm loading a lot of thumbnails on a page via an API endpoint outside of Wagtail, using the technique shown in [Generating dynamic image URLs in Python](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/advanced_topics/images/image_serve_view.html). That seems to work at first, but on closer inspection with Webkit Inspector, it appears that all of the thumbnails are being generated on every page load, not served from cache.

The docs say "the rendition is generated on the first call and subsequent calls are served from a cache."

But in Inspector, I see that every thumbnail generates a 200, not a 304, and they only show up when I select "All" (not Image) in the Network tab. Inspector shows that the calls are of type "document" (not image).

The code I'm using:

```
image = s.main_image()
filter_spec = 'fill-300x186|jpegquality-60'
signature = generate_signature(image.id, filter_spec)
url = reverse('wagtailimages_serve', args=(signature, image.id, filter_spec))
url += image.file.name[len('original_images/'):]
shop['img_url'] = url
```

and an example image URL is:

```
/images/OGJXq3f3oz0AAzD9vFo-HE24Sz8=/414/fill-300x186%7Cjpegquality-60/ceram_marhc_2920120329_0247_1_Sia8Kgl.jpg
```

[image]

Ideas?

**Update:** While the accepted answer works, it turns out we were overcomplicating this. A better approach is not to use the custom signature and url generation routine. Instead, just use Wagtail's `get_rendition()` method:

```
image = s.main_image()
shop['img_url'] = image.get_rendition('fill-300x186|jpegquality-60').url
```

and don't use the URL decorator at all. The images are generated and stored on first access, and return 304 on subsequent accesses just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image URLs generated using Wagtail's `generate_signature` function *are not* cached by the browser automatically. This is because by default there is no `cache-control` setting in the request header for requests to these URLs.

There is a work-around, however (undocumented, [reference](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/911)). To implement a cache-control parameter in the request header for image URLs created using `generate_signature`, you need to decorate your images URL with a cache-control max-age, as follows:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
...
from wagtail.wagtailimages import urls as wagtailimages_urls
from wagtail.utils.urlpatterns import decorate_urlpatterns

# attach cache-control parameter to your /images/* URL
urlpatterns += decorate_urlpatterns(
    [url(r'^images/', include(wagtailimages_urls))],
    cache_control(max_age=1209600)
)
```

All requests to any image URL at `/images` will now have the `cache-control: max-age=120900` parameter in the response header and will be cached by the browser.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @inostia.